# Experience with Paul C Buff's Cyber Commander?

Tags: studio-lighting, wireless-triggers

My studio is mostly comprised of Alien Bee flashes, so I'm looking to pick up the Cyber Commander from PCB.

The device claims to be lightyears ahead of what other remote trigger solutions, so
I'd like to hear people's experiences with the Cyber Commander.

Comment: Any reason not going with PW instead?

Comment: Mainly cost and features.

Comment: This didn't get much response. That's partly because it's about a specific piece of niche gear. But also, it's not phrased as a question, but rather as a discussion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find some good responses here:  http://strobist.blogspot.com/2008/11/cyber-commander-launched-flash-remotes.html

I have not tried the commander, but I own the cybersync transmitters, and love them.  Never had a misfire.  The only problem is that they can toggle on while in a bag, and run out of juice.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 6 years old, but I wanted to give my two cents for those who search this.

My wife and I shot 24 weddings this year using two Alien Bee B800's, each using a cyber commander to control both flashes.

In my experience, when using the Paul C. Buff equipment in a modern venue with clean reliable power, the equipment works like a charm!

Once you understand how to use the two 5-way buttons and understand how to navigate the 3 screens and their various sub-menus, it's pretty nice.  I currently have 3 groups set up for our two lights, Group 1 is Strobe 1, Group 2 is Strobe 2 and Group 3 is both at the same time.  The only problem with doing this is that if you use model lights, they won't be on unless the strobe's group is on.

Anyways, As long as you have the CSR+ or the CSRB+ (with alien bees, since you need to be plugged in, just get the CSR+) the cyber commander works pretty well.  There are plenty of frequencies and channels to use in case you have a bunch of lights or other photographers around.

I'm happy with them when in a good venue, but if there's dirty or unreliable power, it can be very frustrating.